# find() in beautifulsoup4 in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text ("INC000001") from the html code. I have tried many different ways and still unable.

here is what I tried.

```
soup.find("div", {"data-itrac-control-cd":"CS_ID"}).find("span").text()
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I have tried also `.get_text()` no luck

```
<div id="186164592" data-itrac-item-id="186164592" data-itrac-control-cd="CS_ID" class="ui-controlgroup-controls itrac-displayonly">
  <div>
    <span class="display_only ui-body-j itrac-label-nobodybg" id="186164592">INC000001
    </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What’s the URL? Is the page loaded dynamically? does the element appear when doing `soup.prettify()`?

Comment: I am using selenium to go to a page. Then trying to get the data from there. I do believe it is dynamically loaded. @MendelG

Comment: can you share a complete example?

Comment: I might not be able to. It contains sensitive data and i don't think I am allowed to share. This is my very first project so I know just the bare minimums. Anyway to get "INC000001" of off the code snippet I have at the top?

Comment: Don't call `.text()` using parentheses `()`, instead use: `soup.find("div", {"data-itrac-control-cd":"CS_ID"}).find("span").text` Does that work? And if you `print(soup.prettify())` Does the output contain `INC000001`?

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<div id="186164592" data-itrac-item-id="186164592" data-itrac-control-cd="CS_ID" class="ui-controlgroup-controls itrac-displayonly"><div><span class="display_only ui-body-j itrac-label-nobodybg" id="186164592">INC000001</span></div></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.div.div.span.text
```

Output:

```
'INC000001'
```